# Find a number in text file and change signs for its row data using command line

Tags: powershell, batch-file, for-loop, vbscript, find-replace

I am learning batch scripting and the first task that came to me is a Text file   that has more than 1000 rows and is something like this :

```
Organization, month,acct no.,data1,data2,data3,data4
orgA,Jan,1234,78900,78900,78900,78900
```

I need help in writing a batch file which should find a specific `acct no.` (for example: `3456`) and put a '`-`' before `data1, data2,data3,data4`

I have tried :
1)  using batch commands:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (%source%) do SET "org=%%a"   
for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%b in (%source%) do SET "month=%%b"  
for /F "tokens=3 delims=," %%c in (%source%) do SET "acct=%%c"
for /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%d in (%source%) do SET "data1=%%d"
for /F "tokens=5 delims=," %%e in (%source%) do SET "data2=%%e"
for /F "tokens=6 delims=," %%f in (%source%) do SET "data3=%%f"
for /F "tokens=7 delims=," %%g in (%source%) do SET "data4=%%g"

set search=3456
set replace=-%data1%


FOR /F "tokens=* delims=," %%i in ("%source%") do
(set newline=%%i
IF /i %acct% EQU %search%
set newline=!newline:%org%,%month%,%acct%,%replace%! 
echo !newline!>>%target%
)
```

2)VBS:

```
@echo objFile.WriteLine strNewText
@echo objFile.CloseConst ForReading = 
@echo Const FileIn = "test.txt"
@echo Const FileOut = "test_adhoc.txt"  
@echo Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
@echo Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileIn, ForReading)
@echo strText = objFile.ReadAll
@echo objFile.Close
@echo strNewText = Replace(strText, "*,*,3456,*,*,*,*", "*,*,3456,-*,-*,-*,-  *")
@echo Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileOut, ForWriting)
@echo objFile.WriteLine strNewText
@echo objFile.Close
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code you are trying into the question. Perhaps someone will have a suggestion. BTW, this is really easy.

Comment: thanks lit for suggestion!

Comment: you are welcome. You will get a lot more from me, and others, if you paste in your `FOR` loop to the question.

Comment: appreciate your help!@lit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this type of management over large files is that Batch file processing is inherently slow, so any method that may speed up the process is good.

**EDIT**: *Change the signs* of the last four data.

**2ND EDIT**: ... when such a data may have decimal point

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set search=3456

rem Find the number of lines before the target one
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^.*,.*,%search%" source.txt') do set /A lines=%%a-1

rem Reading from the source file
< source.txt (

   rem Copy the lines previous to target one
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do set /P "line=" & echo !line!

   rem Read and process the target line
   set /P "line="
   for /F "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%a in ("!line!") do (
      set "data1=-%%d" & set "data2=-%%e" & set "data3=-%%f" & set "data4=-%%g"
      echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!data1:--=!,!data2:--=!,!data3:--=!,!data4:--=!
   )

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

) > output.txt

move /Y output.txt source.txt
```

In this code the target line is found in one operation via a `findstr` regex that search for the desired `acct no.` in the third comma-separated field of the line. The rest of the program is simple enough to be self-explanatory...

If you have any doubt of any command, you may review its help executing it with /? parameter; for example: `findstr /?`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aacini. this is the only solution that works perfectly. Could you please tell if the varaibles d,e,f,g are already negative , how to make them positive in the same script for different acct no.?

Comment: Well, your request said: "and put a '-' before `data1, data2,data3,data4`"... Just include the same part from @aschipfl answer; I already did it in my code, so just copy it again. May I ask you to select this as "Best answer"?

Comment: I am getting a"missing operator " error. The file is generated but it only converts %%d to positive and rest are just commas.

Comment: Please, post the _original_ target line of the file that cause the error. Sorry, but my crystal ball is not working anymore... **`:(`**

Comment: the target line is OrgD,Feb,9870,-103456.98,-103456.98,-103456.98,-103456.98

Comment: Aha! The program fail when the numbers have _decimal point_! This is the type of details that you should mention from the very beginning... I fixed the code.

Comment: There is one small problem (at least on Windows 7): `findstr` may hang in case the last line in the text file is not terminated with a line-break. Great solution anyway (+1)!

Comment: Hi @Aacini, if there are more than 2 numbers whose sign needs to be changed can we add to the above findstr command?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way of doing what you want -- for **integer** values only (consult the explanatory remarks `rem` in the code):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=.\data.csv"         & rem // (path to CSV file to modify)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%_FILE%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)
set "_ACCT=%~1" & rem // (account number to search, taken from first argument)

rem // Write modified CSV data to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Reset flag to indicate header (first row):
    set "SKIP="
    rem // Read CSV file line by line and extract seven tokens (columns):
    for /F "tokens= 1-7 delims=, eol=," %%A in ('type "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Check whether line is header, skip it from modification in case:
        if defined SKIP (
            rem // Check whether current account number matches:
            if /I "%%C"=="%_ACCT%" (
                rem // Assemble first three call values (do not modify):
                set "PREF=%%A,%%B,%%C"
                rem /* Invert sign of remaining four (numeric) cell values;
                rem    instead, you could also simply write this:
                rem    `echo(%%A,%%B,%%C,-%%D,-%%E,-%%F,-%%G`, but this
                rem    would lead to `--` if a number is already negative: */
                set /A "VAL1=-%%D, VAL2=-%%E, VAL3=-%%F, VAL4=-%%G"
                rem // Return modified line:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                echo(!PREF!,!VAL1!,!VAL2!,!VAL3!,!VAL4!
                endlocal
            ) else (
                rem // Account number does not match, so return original line:
                echo(%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G
            )
        ) else (
            rem // Line is the header, so return original line:
            echo(%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G
            rem // Next line is certainly not a header:
            set "SKIP=#"
        )
    )
)
rem // Replace original CSV file with temporary file:
> nul move /Y "%_TMPF%" "%_FILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

Here is another way -- for **decimal** values, which are actually treated as strings (see remarks `rem`):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=.\data-dec.csv"     & rem // (path to CSV file to modify)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%_FILE%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)
set "_ACCT=%~1" & rem // (account number to search, taken from first argument)

rem // Write modified CSV data to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Reset flag to indicate header (first row):
    set "SKIP="
    rem // Read CSV file line by line and extract seven tokens (columns):
    for /F "tokens= 1-7 delims=, eol=," %%A in ('type "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Check whether line is header, skip it from modification in case:
        if defined SKIP (
            rem // Check whether current account number matches:
            if /I "%%C"=="%_ACCT%" (
                rem // Assemble first three call values (do not modify):
                set "PREF=%%A,%%B,%%C"
                rem // Invert sign of remaining four (numeric) cell values:
                set "VAL1=-%%D" & set "VAL2=-%%E" & set "VAL3=-%%F" & set "VAL4=-%%G"
                rem // Return modified line, avoiding doubled minus-signs:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                echo(!PREF!,!VAL1:--=!,!VAL2:--=!,!VAL3:--=!,!VAL4:--=!
                endlocal
            ) else (
                rem // Account number does not match, so return original line:
                echo(%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G
            )
        ) else (
            rem // Line is the header, so return original line:
            echo(%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G
            rem // Next line is certainly not a header:
            set "SKIP=#"
        )
    )
)
rem // Replace original CSV file with temporary file:
> nul move /Y "%_TMPF%" "%_FILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @aschipfl ! But  will this work for .txt file? I tried this script but its not working. Could you please suggest any other ideas?

Comment: A CSV file is nothing but a text file. Would you please elaborate on "not working", what happens exactly? What is the encoding of the text file you are using? ASCII/ANSI or Unicode?

Comment: some how If else looping does not work , the script runs sets up variables but doesn't modify the original file. Its a UTF-8 w/o BOM.

Comment: Perhaps that is the problem -- I changed the `for /F` line, if you want to retry...

Comment: I am getting a missing operator error for this script too!

Comment: So it is either a problem with your file encoding, or your real data does not comply with the example in your question; hard to say for me without seeing any...

Comment: my output looks like this: OrgD,FEB,9879,103456,,,

Comment: I think it has to do something with that data being in decimal. the original data is 103456.98

Comment: Yes, because the used `set /A` command supports integers only, which you have shown in your question. I added a new version of the script to my answer which can handle decimal numbers too...

Answer (score 1):

```
(    
for /f "tokens=1-7delims=," %%a in (yourfilename.txt) do (
 if "%%c"=="3456" (echo %%a,%%b,%%c,-%%d,-%%e,-%%f,-%%g
 ) else (echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g)
)
)>processedfilename.txt
```

should work. Note that the entire `for` command is enclosed in parentheses to ensure that the output of the `echo`es is redirected to the processedfile name, which must not be the same as the source data filename.

Naturally, `3456` could be replaced by a variable if desired.

Here's the test batch I used - it is exactly the same as the code I posted, just with the filenames constructed to suit my test system.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43354291.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(    
for /f "tokens=1-7delims=," %%a in (%filename1%) do (
 if "%%c"=="3456" (echo %%a,%%b,%%c,-%%d,-%%e,-%%f,-%%g
 ) else (echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g)
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's the input file I used - it's simply your data with a couple of lines duplicated and fixed to suit `account=3456`

> Organization, month,acct no.,data1,data2,data3,data4
>   orgA,Jan,1234,78900,78900,78900,78900
>   orgA,Jan,3456,78900,78900,78900,78900
>   orgA,Jan,6789,78900,78900,78900,78900

and here's the output file

> Organization, month,acct no.,data1,data2,data3,data4
>   orgA,Jan,1234,78900,78900,78900,78900
>   orgA,Jan,3456,-78900,-78900,-78900,-78900
>   orgA,Jan,6789,78900,78900,78900,78900

which appears to be what you require.

Comment: @P.J: some late (but useful) feedback for you. We're keen to encourage folks to be as explicit and detailed when they are describing the problems they are having. "Doesn't work" makes your readers' hearts sink, as it does not provide any more information for them to help you. If you can, please avoid this phrase entirely, forever more, and instead: say what you expected to get, and what you actually got. Remember that you are the only eyes and ears on the problem, so we're relying on the information you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) tag was only added to the question much later, so this answer should be considered out of competition.

**PowerShell** enables a concise and robust solution:

```
$acctNo = 3456

Import-Csv in.csv | ForEach-Object { 
  if ($_.'acct no.' -eq $acctNo) { 
    foreach($prop in (Get-Member -InputObject $_ data*)) {
      $_.$($prop.name) = '-' + $_.$($prop.name)
    }
  }
  $_ 
} # add, e.g., | Out-File -Encoding utf8 out.csv to save to a (different) file.
```

- `Import-Csv file` reads the input CSV file and converts each row into a custom *object* whose properties correspond to the column values of each row.
- The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet processes each such object:

  - Automatic variable `$_` represents the input object at hand in each iteration.
  - `if ($_.'acct no.' -eq $acctNo)` checks for the account number of interest.
  - `Get-Member -InputObject $_ data*` uses reflection to return all properties on the input object whose name starts with `data`.
  - `foreach(...)` processes all matching properties in a loop.
  - `$_.$($prop.name) = '-' + $_.$($prop.name)` updates each matching property by prepending `-` to the existing value.

Note that you can't save the results directly back to the *same* file - unless you use `(Import-Csv in.csv)` instead of just `Import-Csv in.csv`, but that means that the entire input file will be read into memory *as a whole*.